# What's the purpose of de in this sentence?

Tags: usage, terminologie

What does the "d'" in d'écrire mean? Does it reference the statement the author just made? I.e. it would mean: and of this the naif Kinsey writes...?

Il ne s'agit plus de la petite tante que tout le monde connaît, mais d'une personne sur deux - votre voisin, ou votre fils, pourquoi pas ? Et le naïf Kinsey d'écrire :...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an infinitive prefix, *de* can play a similar role than "to" in English (to write).

Here, there is a rare literary usage of *de*. The sentence means :

> ...and the naive Kinsey [then] writes...